# Elasticsearch cant merge object mapping on the first document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to index a document, but I'm getting the `Can't merge a non object mapping [schedules.data] with an object mapping [schedules.data]` message.

But this is the first document I'm trying to index in the this index. Why is it trying to merge mappings when there shouldn't be any mapping to begin with?

Comment: "there shouldn't be any mapping to begin with" What do you mean by this?

Comment: That I just deleted the index, and this is the first document I'm trying to insert. From what I understand this error is supposed to happen when you try to insert a document where a field does not have the same type as the same field of a previous document. But this is the first document. So how can the automatic mapping fail?

Comment: Can you show the steps to recreate it?

Comment: I can't show you the data I'm afraid, but I just realized that `schedules.data` is an array (of arrays). Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing anything, but you're probably right  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you schedules is a list of objects.
So if this is you first document it says that **inside** schedules.

Inside one object data is an object

And inside other object of schedules data field has some data that is primitive data types such as string or something.

Ultimately this happens when you in the same document you have two objects of schedule in which  data field has different mapping -> object and some other.

For eg

```
{
  "schedules": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": "value4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Data having different types in different objects of schedules of the same document.

So elasticsearch is not able to decide what mapping of data is.